# how can I use the variable from class A in class B (python)

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, inheritance

I want to use the variable (file) in class (PageOne) I'm not good in python so even when I did my research I couldn't do it, can you help me please ?
My project is to take a csv file from the user(in WelcomePage) and it will pick a random row from that file and show it in (PageOne).

i tried different ways but always the same error message (name 'file' is not defined)

```
from cProfile import label
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import title
from typing import Container
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 


class MainFrame (tk.Tk):




   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

       self.titlefont = tkfont.Font(family = 'Verdana',size=12,
                                   weight = "bold", slant='roman')

       container =tk.Frame()
       container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

       self.id =tk.StringVar()
       self.id.set("Mister")

       self.listing = {}

       for p in (WelcomePage, PageOne):
           page_name = p.__name__
           frame = p(parent = container, controller = self)
           frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
           self.listing[page_name] = frame

       self.up_frame('WelcomePage')

   def up_frame(self,page_name):
       page = self.listing[page_name]
       page.tkraise()

class WelcomePage(tk.Frame):
   global file
   def open_file():
       
       file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('I', '*csv')])
       if file is not None:
           pass
       return file

   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.controller = controller
       self.id = controller.id

       label = tk.Label(self,text= "Welcome Page \n"+ controller.id.get(),
                        font= controller.titlefont)
       label.pack()
       lod = tk.Button (self, text="Select a file",
                        command= lambda:open_file())
       lod.pack()
       bou = tk.Button (self, text="Submit",
                        command= lambda: controller.up_frame("PageOne"))
       bou.pack()
       
   






class PageOne(WelcomePage,tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.controller = controller
       self.id = controller.id

       label = tk.Label(self,text= "Page One \n"+ controller.id.get(),
                        font= controller.titlefont)
       label.pack()

       bou = tk.Button (self, text="back to main",
                        command= lambda: controller.up_frame("WelcomePage"))
       bou.pack()
       
       
       

       

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = MainFrame()
   app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can make `file` an instance variable of `MainFrame`, then you can use `controller.file` to access it inside those frames.

Answer (score 0):

try this --
use the keyword global in the method as well for the variable purpose

then your error of file name is not defined should resolved.

```
   def open_file():
   global file
   file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('I', '*csv')])
   if file is not None:
       pass
   return file
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8 used Walrus. Put keyword inside function

**Before**:

```
   def open_file():       
       file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('I', '*csv')])
       if file is not None:
           pass
       return file
```

**After Walrus**:

```
def open_file():
    global file
    if (file := askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('I', '*py' is not None)])):
       pass
    return file
```